# AngularJS - scope differences

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a simple fiddle, to illustrate the differences between `scopes (true, false, {})`.

But I can't understand, why it's not working as I expect...

1) Why changing the "`val`" on controller, affects `directiveTwo` with "`scope:true`". If I change the value in directive, then controller stops to affect it.

2) Why `directiveThree` has Isolated scope, but it inherits the values from controller (so value created in `directiveOne`, passed to it to), changing the value in controller affects the `directiveThree`. When I change the value from that directive, it affects the controllers value. Shouldn't Isolated scope be Isolated?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVxAh/1/)
HTML:

```
<div id="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Controller: <input ng-model="val"/> <b>{{val}}</b> Child: <b>{{childVal}}</b>
    <br/>
    <div directive-one>
        Directive 1: <input ng-model="val"/> Val: <b>{{val}}</b> Child: <b>{{childVal}}</b>
    </div>
    <div directive-two>
        Directive 2: <input ng-model="val"/> Val: <b>{{val}}</b> Child: <b>{{childVal}}</b>
    </div>
    <div directive-three>
        Directive 3: <input ng-model="val"/> Val: <b>{{val}}</b> Child: <b>{{childVal}}</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("ctrl1", function($scope){
    $scope.val = "CTRL";
})
.directive("directiveOne", function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.childVal = 1;
        },
        scope:false //or not defined at all
    };
})
.directive("directiveTwo", function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.childVal = 2;
        },
        scope:true
    };
})
.directive("directiveThree", function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.childVal = 3;
        },
        scope:{}
    };
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp'), ["myApp"]);
```

Comment: Maybe Angular is defaulting to `transclude: true` for your directives? Then `val` would be available in the directives, and bound to the outermost controller's model, explaining the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Thx, I fixed the fiddle...I don't see that directives are transcluded.

Comment: Yeah, I found a fix for the fiddle, and have been playing around a bit. If you move the contents of your directive DIVs into the template for the directives, and use `scope: {}`you'll get the behavior you're expecting. So Angular likely puts the DIVs' contents into the outer controller scope because it doesn't see it as part of the directive when it's not defined as the directive's template.

Comment: Doesn't look like Batarang works with JSFiddle, but try using it on that script locally; it will show you which scopes you have and what is placed where. Then play around with the code and see what changes that makes to the scopes. That's probably the best way to figure this stuff out.

Comment: Yep, with template this works. Didn't knew about the importance of template in this case. But I still don't understand, why in directiveTwo (with scope:true), changing the value on controller affects directive. Only after modifying the value in directive, the controller changes stop to affect directive value.

Comment: It works as follows when all the contents of all the directives are correctly placed in a template:  Directive 1 has no scope on its own, so it uses the scope the directive is placed in. Directive 2 appears to have a lazily instantiated scope based on a reference to the scope the directive is placed in; which means the new scope isn't created until something is explicitly placed in it. Until then it's _the same_ object as the parent scope. Directive 3 has its own scope that you explicitly instantiate to a new empty object; which means there's no lingering reference to the parent scope.

Comment: The behavior in Directive 2 seems to be buggy then, as it's hard to see how that behavior is by design.

Comment: Directive 2 acts that way due to prototypal inheritance.  There's a good explanation here:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

The reason DirectiveTwo may take changes from the controller, but the controller won't change when DirectiveTwo changes the value (...) is because when is expected to let the child change the value of the parent, the bare values won't work.

What is a bare-value?

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("ctrl1", function($scope){
    $scope.val ={
        value = "CTRL"   <--- This way a child will inherit the OBJECT and NOT a COPY
    };
    $scope.val = "CTRL"; <--- This way the child inherits a COPY of the BARE-VALUE
})
```